# WIX installer how do remove install

Tags: installation, wix

I created a basic installer.
It takes a file from c:\temp.log and copy it to a directory that is being read from registry.
Where is the un-installer ? How does it add link to Windows "Add remove programs" ?

What am i missing here?
On install i need to copy the file and then to stop/start a certain service.
On Un-install i need to remove that file+folder and then to stop/start a certain service.

Thanks

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="325c4bfd-6614-43e9-aedb-93661295352d" Name="install" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="install" UpgradeCode="4307526e-3902-40d0-991b-bacff9b3d71b">

    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" />

    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Property Id="APPDIR">
        <RegistrySearch Id="APPDIRECTORY" Type="raw" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\APP\APPInstalPath" Name="InstallationPath" />
    </Property>

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="APPDIR">
            <Component Id="ProductComponent" Guid="93118c45-f0c0-4c9e-9168-8ea905e9427c">
                <File Id="pluggin" Source="C://setup.log" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
            </Component>     
        </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="install" Level="1">
        <ComponentRef Id="ProductComponent" />
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="Product.Generated" />
    </Feature>
  </Product>
</Wix>
```

Comment: I get the the proper way to remove it is to right click the .msi file and choose un-install. so i need to add shortcut to "Add remove programs" dialog ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The listing in Add/Remove programs is whatever *Name* you specified in the *Product* tag. In your case, the name in Add/Remove programs is **install**:

```
<Product Id="325c4bfd-6614-43e9-aedb-93661295352d" Name="install"
```

Comment: thanks, the "install" did not list it, but when i changed the name, it did list it.